# Conexión a base de datos Mysql abierta pero no inserta

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos, .net

Tengo una pequeña aplicación de escritorio en c# y ya he abierto la conexión a base de datos, pero al momento de insertar datos desde el formulario y actualizar la base de datos no aparece ningún registro:

```
string DatabaseName = "vehiculos";
string connstring = string.Format("Server=localhost; database={0}; UID=root; password=", DatabaseName);
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

System.Console.WriteLine("entré");

connection.Open();

string placa;
placa = textBox1.ToString();

string insert = "INSERT INTO PRUEBA (PLACA,HORA_ENTRADA) VALUES( " + placa + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) ";

var order = new MySqlCommand(insert, connection);
order.ExecuteNonQuery();
textBox1.Clear();
```

agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar

Comment: El método ExecuteNonQuery devuelve un entero que indica el número de filas afectadas por la consulta, ¿qué te devuelve a ti cuando la ejecutas, -1?

Answer (score 9):

Buenas,

Tienes un error sintáctico en la consulta SQL:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO PRUEBA (PLACA,HORA_ENTRADA) VALUES( " + placa + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) ";
```

Si te fijas antes de añadir `placa` no le pones la comilla simple, pero después si le pones.

Si pusieras un `try/catch` te saldria un error de sintaxis SQL.

La sentencia quedaría de ésta forma:

```
string insert = "INSERT INTO PRUEBA (PLACA,HORA_ENTRADA) VALUES( '" + placa + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) ";
```

Un saludo.